# Any way to enable https connection in PHPStorm debug feature?

Tags: ssl, phpstorm, xdebug

I am running a pieced-together WAMP server and working on an app that only runs in SSL. I need to debug it but PHPStorm does not offer any ways to set debug to understand SSL, result: I get a 'Bad Request' Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To reiterate, I am running Apache2.2 and php5.3.9 with php_xdebug-2.2.7-5.3-vc9 configured, both installed into my windows environment. Not optimal process but required for the job I am doing.

Comment: I'm not sure what SSL has to do with actual xdebug (outside of IDE, of course). Can you please clarify how do you launch debug session and where that "Bad Request" comes from?

Comment: To simply put, I configure the server as localhost, and when I configure xdebug and I choose that server, it will use it as "http://localhost". If I configure the server with port 443, still the same thing happens. If I configure the server as "https://localhost" it returns as "http://https://localhost" if I set it to be a remote server, still the same thing happens.

Comment: In the application I need to debug there are over 1,000 instances where https is used, so changing that to http to create a development platform is not feasible.

Comment: I'm sorry again .. but could you clarify this (the place where and how you configuring this https URL) with a screenshot (you can blur real names -- I just need to see the place and where/how you are doing it). Also please describe how do you launch your debug session (I assume it's all initiated in IDE?)

Comment: Your server can run https happily via apache, and can talk to xdebug without using ssl. So please be specific about your problem area

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but I got here from google.  HTTPS will work with xdebug fine if you redirect your traffic on port 80 to HTTPS/443.

With Apache you can add a virtual host like so [(from here)](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName mysite.example.com
   DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
   Redirect permanent /secure https://mysite.example.com/secure
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
   ServerName mysite.example.com
   DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
   SSLEngine On
# etc...
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm using nginx and php-fpm so I've added this block to redirect

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

More info [here](https://bjornjohansen.no/redirect-to-https-with-nginx).  Using this and leaving my PHPStorm server configured to :80 hits https, connects to xdebug and breaks normally.  Ideally we could change the protocol in PHPStorm but I don't see an option.